# Server Error in '/' Application in Asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in Asp.net mvc 4. I created a class in Model part that its name is "User". Then I created an object of this class and sent it to one view. I added "@model projectName.Model.User" to the View part. After execution this error(Server Error in '/' Application) was shown. How can I handle it?
thanks a lot.

```
namespace Sprint1.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Login/
    
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Models.User Ouser = new User();
            return View(User);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignUp()
        {
            return View();
        }        
    }
}
```

This part is my View for the first action.

```
@model Sprint1.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login Page</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
   
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Login</legend>
        <p>
     
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(User => User.name)
            
            
        </p>
      
         
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"  onclick=return("~/Views/SignUp") />
        </p>
       
    </fieldset>
   

}
```

And the error page is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Sprint1.Models.User'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Sprint1.Models.User'.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Please submit your view and action. Also submit the error.

Comment: Then what is the error message? Pleas add in your answer don't put in commend.

Comment: The question was corrected.

Comment: See my answer then. Tell me if not works.

Answer (score 0):

In your index action method replace `View(User)` with `View(Ouser)`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Models.User Ouser = new User();
    // User is a property in your controller with type of `IPrincipal`
    // But your new user variable name is Ouser; 
    //return View(User);

    return View(Ouser);

}
```